# How to fit MLP Classifier to specific dataset structure and content?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I have a dataset with statistical values and objective measures for image quality (all values are between 0 and 1). Those values are taken from images produced with Laplacian pyramid blending as a fused result form under and overexposed image pairs. The dataset contains values from 4 result images of each pair (100 pairs in dataset total) chosen from higher decomposition levels with the best quality. The output is 1 on that image with the best-perceived quality chosen by MOS from people gathered from a survey (rest 3 votes are 0).

The whole idea of this is to train model which can estimate on which level 
(respectively which picture) of Laplacian pyramid is the "best" result image from decomposition.

My question here is,

How should I train the classifier, because output 1 for best image in that group of output images from the same pair (over/uder exposed) doesn't have the same "weight" (or meaning) as in another pair which is correlated with images from the same group?

For example,

Input images = [Im1, Im2, Im3, Im4, Im5, Im6, Im7, Im8 ... ]
Output       = [ 0 ,  0 ,  1 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  1  ... ]

Images: Im1, Im2, Im3, Im4 are fused result from pair 1 and image Im3 is the best image chosen by people with MOS. For pair 2 it is Im8 (or equivalently 4th image)

Should I divide images into groups as pairs and fit 100 times, like:

Group1 = [Im1, Im2, Im3, Im4] -> Output1 = [ 0 ,  0 ,  1 ,  0 ]

Group2 = [Im5, Im6, Im7, Im8] -> Output2 = [ 0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  1 ]

... and so on.

and then:

clf.fit(Group1, Output1)
clf.fit(Group2, Output2)

... and so on.
or should I use **partial_fit** for same?

Any other smarter idea and advice ?

Comment: That depends on what do you want your model to predict? All four labels for a sample or a single one.

Comment: All four labels for a sample.
If i test vector with 2 gorups of images [im1.1., im1.2. , im1.3., im1.4., im2.1., im2.2. , im2.3., im2.4.] to get output vector like [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1] which means: im1.3. and im2.4. are best predictions according parameters learned before

Comment: You can try something like `[Im1, Im2, Im3, Im4] -> [Index of best image]`. In this way your problem is reduced to a multi-class problem with classes [1-4] to predict.

Comment: Yes, depending on votes I will classify images in four classes instead of two that's also a good alternative.

Comment: Also you did not answer to me, is it better, in either case, to train the whole dataset as it is or train 100 groups separately so the model can conclude dependency for example that worser image in the previous level  has bigger or smaller parameter value, for example, signal-to-noise ratio (it is one of the parameters i have)

Comment: That I cant say. You have to try both and see what gives better performance. Or else ask this question on https://stats.stackexchange.com